# Why are my indexed fields being returned in a random order rather than alphabetical (ASC) order?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of `users` -

```
id INT
account_id INT
name VARCHAR
email VARCHAR
```

And I have added an index for `(account_id, name)` so that users are returned in alphabetical order by `name`.

However, in some of my queries the users are returned in alphabetical order on the `name` field, but in others they are not, and are returned in a random order - and my index does not seem to be applied.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE account_id = 56;  // Index is applied. 
                                            // Sorted by name in ASC order. 

SELECT * FROM users WHERE account_id = 110; // Index is not applied. 
                                            // Not sorted by name.
```

What might be the reason for this?

(Could it be related to the number of records the query fetches? Could it be because of partitions?)

Kindly help.

Comment: Try to google  about index cardinality to see when MySQL might decide not to use an index. Also, do post output of `EXPLAIN`  when asking questions related to MySQL and SELECTs.

Answer (score 3):

An index does not gurantee the order of results. Indexes are used to make searching easier. And in this case, since you are searching by account_id, that would be the only index that would be used.

If you want your results ordered use an "ORDER BY" clause.

Comment: Thankyou. If I use "order by " my problem is solved. However, I would like to know why index is applied for few queries and why not in few other queries.

Comment: It is nothing to do with the index. The fact the results are returned in alphabetical order is most likely entirely coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what an index does in MySQL. An index is an internal mechanism which allows your database to perform faster on certain fields.

Any data you query can be returned in *any* order, unless you specifically include an `ORDER BY` clause.

If you want to sort users by name, your query would become `SELECT * FROM users WHERE account_id = 56 ORDER BY name ASC`.